# MIssing border in table with multicolumn and multirow with hyphenated column headings

Tags: multicolumn, multirow, border

I am missing the right border in one the columns where there is a multirow.
Have tried a bunch of things.
Here is an example.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol,graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnsep}{5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{1cm}>{\raggedright}p{1cm}>{\raggedright}p{1cm}>{\raggedright}p{1cm}>{\raggedright}p{1cm}>{\raggedright}p{1cm}>{\raggedright}p{1cm}>{\raggedright}p{1cm}>{\raggedright}p{1cm}>{\raggedright}p{1cm}>{\raggedright}p{1cm}>{\raggedright}p{1cm}>{\raggedright}p{1.6cm}>{\raggedright}p{1.5cm}} \hline
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  & \multicolumn{10}{|c|}{\textbf{End-Use Sectors}} & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}p{1.6cm}|}{\multirow{2}{=}{\textbf{E. Power Sector}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} \tabularnewline \cline{2-11} 
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{5}{|>{\centering}p{5cm}|}{\textbf{Transportation}} & \multicolumn{5}{|>{\centering}p{5cm}|}{\textbf{Total}} & &  \tabularnewline \cline{2-12}
      & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}p{1cm}|}{\textbf{Primary}} & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}p{1cm}|}{\textbf{Electricity}} & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}p{1cm}|}{\textbf{End-Use}} & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}p{1cm}|}{\textbf{Energy Losses}} & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}p{1cm}|}{\textbf{Total Energy}} &
       \multicolumn{1}{|>{\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}p{1cm}|}{\textbf{Primary}} & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}p{1cm}|}{\textbf{Electricity}} & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}p{1cm}|}{\textbf{End-Use}} & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}p{1cm}|}{\textbf{Energy Losses}} & 
       \multicolumn{1}{|>{\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}p{1cm}|}{\textbf{Total Energy}} &
       \multicolumn{1}{|>{\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}p{1.6cm}|}{\textbf{Primary}} & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}p{1.5cm}}{\textbf{Primary Total}}  \tabularnewline \hline
    1949  & 7880  & 22    & 7902  & 88    & 7990  & 27628 & 868   & 28497 & 3471  & 31968 & 4339  & 31968 \tabularnewline
    1950  & 8383  & 23    & 8407  & 86    & 8492  & 29919 & 994   & 30914 & 3685  & 34599 & 4679  & 34599 \tabularnewline
    1951  & 8933  & 24    & 8958  & 84    & 9042  & 31883 & 1127  & 33010 & 3944  & 36953 & 5071  & 36954 \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: You may replace `lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in` with `margin=1in`.

Answer (score 1):

After clean-up mess in your code, I got the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol,graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \small
\begin{tabular}{|l | *{12}{P{1.5cm}|} } 
    \hline
    &   \multicolumn{10}{c|}{\textbf{End-Use Sectors}} 
        &   \multirow{2}{=}{\textbf{E. Power Sector}} 
            &       \\
    \cline{2-11}
    &   \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Transportation}} 
        &   \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Total}} 
            &   &   \\
    \cline{2-12}
    & \textbf{Primary}
        & \textbf{Electricity}
            & \textbf{End-Use}
                & \textbf{Energy Losses}
                    & \textbf{Total Energy}
                        & \textbf{Primary}
                            & \textbf{Electricity}
                                & \textbf{End-Use}
                                    & \textbf{Energy Losses}
                                        & \textbf{Total Energy}
                                            & \textbf{Primary}
                                                & \textbf{Primary Total}    \\ 
    \hline
1949    & 7880  & 22    & 7902 & 88    & 7990 & 27628 
        & 868   & 28497 & 3471 & 31968 & 4339 & 31968                       \\
1950    & 8383  & 23    & 8407 & 86    & 8492 & 29919 
        & 994   & 30914 & 3685 & 34599 & 4679 & 34599                       \\
1951    & 8933  & 24    & 8958 & 84    & 9042 & 31883 
        & 1127  & 33010 & 3944 & 36953 & 5071 & 36954                       \\
\end{tabular}%
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
However, code can be significantly short if you willing to use the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}    
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \small
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {l *{12}{X[c]} },
             colsep=4pt,
             row{1-3} = {font=\bfseries, m}
             }
    &   \SetCell[c=10]{c}   End-Use Sectors 
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}   E. Power Sector
                                                &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}   \\
    &    \SetCell[c=5]{c}   Transportation 
        &   &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=5]{c}   Total 
                            &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    & Primary
        & Electri\-city
            & End-Use
                & Energy Losses
                    & Total Energy
                        & Primary
                            & Electri\-city
                                & End-Use
                                    & Energy Losses
                                        & Total Energy
                                            & Primary
                                                & Primary Total \\
1949    & 7880  & 22    & 7902 & 88    & 7990 & 27628
        & 868   & 28497 & 3471 & 31968 & 4339 & 31968           \\
1950    & 8383  & 23    & 8407 & 86    & 8492 & 29919
        & 994   & 30914 & 3685 & 34599 & 4679 & 34599           \\
1951    & 8933  & 24    & 8958 & 84    & 9042 & 31883
        & 1127  & 33010 & 3944 & 36953 & 5071 & 36954           \\
\end{tblr}%
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Compilation result is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would go even further than @Zarko goes in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660415/5001) and (a) get rid of all vertical lines and replace the ill-spaced horizontal lines with well-spaced horizontal rules courtesy of the `booktabs` package and (b) drop the **bold-facing** in table's header rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow,pdflscape}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules

\usepackage{array} % for \newcolumntype macro
\newcolumntype{Q}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} *{11}{c} Q{1.4cm} c @{}} 
\toprule
& 
\multicolumn{10}{c}{End-Use Sectors} &
\multicolumn{1}{Q{1.4cm}}{\multirow{2.4}{=}{E.\ Power Sector}} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-11} 
& 
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Transportation} & 
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Total} &  \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-11} \cmidrule(lr){12-12}
&
\multicolumn{1}{Q{1.2cm}}{Primary} & 
\multicolumn{1}{Q{1.2cm}}{Electricity} & 
\multicolumn{1}{Q{1.2cm}}{End-Use} & 
\multicolumn{1}{Q{1.2cm}}{Energy Losses} & 
\multicolumn{1}{Q{1.2cm}}{Total Energy} &
\multicolumn{1}{Q{1.2cm}}{Primary} & 
\multicolumn{1}{Q{1.2cm}}{Electricity} & 
\multicolumn{1}{Q{1.2cm}}{End-Use} & 
\multicolumn{1}{Q{1.2cm}}{Energy Losses} & 
\multicolumn{1}{Q{1.2cm}}{Total Energy} &
\multicolumn{1}{Q{1.4cm}}{Primary} & 
\multicolumn{1}{Q{1.3cm}@{}}{Primary Total}  \\ 
\midrule
1949 & 7880 & 22 & 7902 & 88 & 7990 & 27628 & \phantom{0}868 & 28497 & 3471 & 31968 & 4339 & 31968 \\
1950 & 8383 & 23 & 8407 & 86 & 8492 & 29919 & \phantom{0}994 & 30914 & 3685 & 34599 & 4679 & 34599 \\
1951 & 8933 & 24 & 8958 & 84 & 9042 & 31883 & 1127 & 33010 & 3944 & 36953 & 5071 & 36954 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```